# Filter data in mysql database using datatime for (today,7 days, 1month and 1year)

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get filters result using timestemp. but how?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, check out the [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask questions to get the most out of this site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if you want to filter on today, you will need to use:

```
SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date_field`,'%d%m%y') = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE(),'%d%m%y')
```

CURDATE() is MySQL's way of saying today, you can test this with a simple:

```
SELECT CURDATE()
```

So if your date field in your database is equal to `CURDATE()` then it's today - the `DATE_FORMAT` is to make sure your date field and the way the system will represent today's date are the same (such as, in my database, my date field is actually datetime so would never equal otherwise).

`CURDATE()` also supports modifiers, so, if you'd like seven days ago you could say `CURDATE() - 7` such as:

```
SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date_field`,'%d%m%y') = DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()-7,'%d%m%y')
```

If you'd like everything after seven days ago you simply adjust from equals to greater or equal:

```
SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`date_field`,'%d%m%y') >= DATE_FORMAT(CURDATE()-7,'%d%m%y')
```

A month we'll deal with differently (given months don't have the same number of days)

```
SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE `date_field` >= DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH, '%Y/%m/01' )
```

And `INTERVAL` can be used for your year too:

```
SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE `date_field` >= DATE_FORMAT( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR, '%Y/%m/01' )
```

Hope this helps